# How to get all <img src> of a web page in iOS UIWebView?

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

everyone.

I'm trying to get all image urls of the current page in UIWebView.

So, here is my code.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView*)webView {
    NSString *firstImageUrl = [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');images[0].src.toString();"];
    NSString *imageUrls = [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"var images= document.getElementsByTagName('img');var imageUrls = "";for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++){var image = images[i];imageUrls += image.src;imageUrls += \\’,\\’;}imageUrls.toString();"];
    NSLog(@"firstUrl : %@", firstImageUrl);
    NSLog(@"images : %@",imageUrls);
}
```

1st NSLog returns correct image's src, but 2nd NSLog returns nothing.

```
2013-01-25 00:51:23.253 WebDemo[3416:907] firstUrl: https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif
2013-01-25 00:51:23.254 WebDemo[3416:907] images :
```

I don't know why.
Please help me...

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Perrohunter pointed out one `NSRegularExpression` solution, which is great. If you don't want to enumerate the array of matches, you can use the block-based [`enumerateMatchesInString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009708-CH1-SW10) method, too:

```
NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(<img\\s[\\s\\S]*?src\\s*?=\\s*?['\"](.*?)['\"][\\s\\S]*?>)+?"
                                                                       options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                         error:&error];

[regex enumerateMatchesInString:yourHTMLSourceCodeString
                        options:0
                          range:NSMakeRange(0, [yourHTMLSourceCodeString length])
                     usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {

                         NSString *img = [yourHTMLSourceCodeString substringWithRange:[result rangeAtIndex:2]];
                         NSLog(@"img src %@",img);
                     }];
```

I've also updated the regex pattern to deal with the following issues:

- there can be  attributes between the start `img` tag and the `src` attribute;
- there can be attributes after the `src` attribute and before the `>`;
- there can be newline characters in the middle of an `img` tag (the `.` captures everything except newline character);
- the `src` attribute value can be quoted with `'` as well as `"`; and
- there can be spaces between `src` and the `=` as well as between the `=` and the subsequent value.

I freely recognize that reading regex patterns is painful for the uninitiated, and perhaps other solutions might make more sense (the JSON suggestion by Joris, using scanners, etc.). But if you wanted to use regex, the above pattern might cover a few more permutations of the `img` tag, and `enumerateMatchesInString` might be ever so slightly more efficient than `matchesInString`.

Comment: Thanks!! This regex is more useful. You are great. So, I changed "Accepted answer". Sorry, perrohunter... I need to study regex.

Answer (score 11):

I don't like regular expressions, so here's my answer without them.

The javascript indented for clarification:

```
// javascript to execute:
(function() {
    var images=document.querySelectorAll("img");
    var imageUrls=[];
    [].forEach.call(images, function(el) {
        imageUrls[imageUrls.length] = el.src;
    }); 
    return JSON.stringify(imageUrls);
})()
```

You'll notice I return a JSON string here. To read this back in Objective-C:

```
NSString *imageURLString = [self.webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"(function() {var images=document.querySelectorAll(\"img\");var imageUrls=[];[].forEach.call(images, function(el) { imageUrls[imageUrls.length] = el.src;}); return JSON.stringify(imageUrls);})()"];

// parse json back into an array
NSError *jsonError = nil;
NSArray *urls = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[imageURLString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:0 error:&jsonError];

if (!urls) {
    NSLog(@"JSON error: %@", jsonError);
    return;
}

NSLog(@"Images : %@", urls);
```

Comment: For those of you who don't like regex to parse html, refer to this classic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Thanks. That's actually more for those who still like regex. Anyone that doesn't like regex has probably already read/experienced that :)

Comment: @JorisKluivers Thanks! Your code worked well. Because I am not good at regex, I feel an affinity for your suggestion.

Comment: I have nothing against using regex but this javascript method is lightning fast compared to any kind of string parsing I have benchmarked.

Answer (score 6):

You could achieve this running a regex on the loaded webview html source code

```
NSString *yourHTMLSourceCodeString = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.innerHTML"];

    NSError *error = NULL;
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(<img src=\"(.*?)\">)+?"
                                                                           options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                             error:&error];

    NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:yourHTMLSourceCodeString
                                      options:0
                                        range:NSMakeRange(0, [yourHTMLSourceCodeString length])];

    NSLog(@"total matches %d",[matches count]);

    for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
        NSString *img = [yourHTMLSourceCodeString substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:2]] ;
        NSLog(@"img src %@",img);
    }
```

This is a pretty basic regex that matches anything inside a  tag, it would need more details if your images have more attributes such as class or id's

Comment: sorry, I missed that, it's supporused to be match

Comment: By the way, if you want to go nuts, you should be more careful about the `img` tag and use a regular expression like `@"(<img\\s[\\s\\S]*?src=['\"](.*?)['\"][\\s\\S]*?>)+?"` because (a) you can have attributes between the start `img` tag and the `src` attribute; (b) you might have attributes after the `src` tag and before the `>`; (c) you can have newline characters in the middle of a `img` tag; (d) I think `src` attribute value can be quoted with `'` as well as `"`; etc.

Comment: @Rob That's a great suggestion Rob! I know my regex needed more work, I just wrote a pretty simple one :P

Comment: @Rob Your regular expression is very good. This is what I need. Last time, you helped me. Thank you very much.

Comment: @user1928537 very good (I didn't recognize your handle ... you always could change your "display name" to something more memorable by going to [your page](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1928537/) and hitting "edit"). Anyway, I noticed the regex wasn't handling spaces before and after the `=`, a correction I've added to my answer in which I point out another regex method you could use. I don't want you to change your "accepted answer", but I also didn't feel right editing perrohunter's excellent answer, either.

Answer (score 2):

With given html, you can use [SwiftSoup](https://github.com/scinfu/SwiftSoup) library. Using **Swift 3**

```
do {
    let doc: Document = try SwiftSoup.parse(html)
    let srcs: Elements = try doc.select("img[src]")
    let srcsStringArray: [String?] = srcs.array().map { try? $0.attr("src").description }
    // do something with srcsStringArray
    } catch Exception.Error(_, let message) {
        print(message)
    } catch {
        print("error")
    }
```