# Get image URL from rss

Tags: ios, swift, image, rss

I'd like to get the first image URL of an post from this rss file: http://www.macnotes.de/feed/

How can I do this in Swift?

I got the description, the title an the author like this:

```
    let item = feedItems[indexPath.row] as MWFeedItem
    let vc = ViewController()
    vc.text.text = item.description
    vc.author.text = item.author
    vc.layer.text = item.title
```

Comment: You can't easily as there's not an attribute for an image (like title, author etc). You would need to trail through the html content to find the first img tag and grab the url for it.

Comment: @123 on github.com look for html or xml parser

Comment: Any luck with my answer

Comment: Try this framework, it will make things much easier: https://github.com/cezheng/Fuzi

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comments, there's not an easy way to grab the image as its hidden amongst the content html.

To achieve this you can use regex to look through the content for img tags:

[How to get all <img src> of a web page in iOS UIWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14505764/how-to-get-all-img-src-of-a-web-page-in-ios-uiwebview)

Hope this is useful.